# How to get linux 'diff' to work with regex expression in bash

Tags: linux, regular-expression, diff

I have two files, expected.out and actual.out with:
`PID(12345)`
`PID(01234)`
respectively.

I want diff to ignore the line if only the 5 numbers are different, so diff would return empty. The idea is to for diff to ignore logs that have different PIDs but are otherwise identical.

The following doesn't work:

`diff -I '\([0-9]{5}\)' -I '\([0-9]{5}\)' expected.out actual.out`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match the beginning `^` and end of the line `$` and also match the string `PID` (you don't want `FOO(12345)` and `BAR(12345)` to be ignored):

```
diff -I '^PID([0-9]\{5\})$' expected.out actual.out
```

It's safer to match one or more digits than to assume that each PID has 5 digits:

```
diff -I '^PID([0-9]\+)$' expected.out actual.out
```